# Binding element 'dispatch' implicitly has an 'any' type. var dispatch: any

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I follow this example about `redux` but I write with TypeScript.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos-with-undo

I get trouble in `AddTodo.tsx` file.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

const AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
let input: any

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (!input.value.trim()) {
        return
      }
      dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
      input.value = ''
    }}>
      <input ref={node => {
        input = node
      }} />
      <button type="submit">
        Add Todo
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

The `dispatch` parameter does not allowed. The error says:

> [ts] Binding element 'dispatch' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe is a types issue. Try to add types in your props like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';

interface AddTodoProps { 
  dispatch : Dispatch<{}> 
 }


const AddTodo = (props : AddTodoProps) => {
let input: any

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (!input.value.trim()) {
        return
      }
      props.dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
      input.value = ''
    }}>
      <input ref={node => {
        input = node
      }} />
      <button type="submit">
        Add Todo
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}

export default connect()(AddTodo)
```

Comment: could you check out my repo `https://github.com/khuong291/React_ToDo`. It can not compiled.

Comment: It can't be compiled because of tslint rules you wrote on `tslint.json` file. This rules must be respected before the compilation.

Comment: The solution worked for me, however, I am encountering a TypeScript error message stating that 'Type '{}' does not satisfy the constraint 'Action<any>'.' 
Is there a way to resolve this issue? @bonheury